# Hibernate IllegalArgumentException

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I get a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: path.to.MyEntity. 
I have explicitly specified the provider in persistence.xml using:

```
<persistence-unit ...>
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
</persistence-unit>
```

and MyEntity is annotated appropriately.
The hibernate portions of the exception trace:
...

```
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:186)
```

...
What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

It was a classpath issue.  I had to put META-INF folder (inside which persistence.xml was kept) in the root classpath.